# Microsoft chatbot - remove hyperlinks in bot response

Tags: c#, botframework

We need to show links without hyplinks in bot response.
For e.g "abc.com" should appear as plain text, not with a clickable link.

[image]

Tried setting TextFormat as "markdown", "plaintext", but no change.

```
var answer = context.Activity.CreateReply();
answer.TextFormat = "markdown";
answer.Text = $"{response}";
```

Ref: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/1152

Thanks!

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: Using Directline channel

Comment: Can you post the content of your `answer.Text` value in your question? To check if you can do a workaround with it

Comment: Are you using Web Chat or your own Direct Line client?

Comment: It is a webchat. answer.Text will be plain text - "some dummy response abc.com"

Comment: Are you using Web Chat v3 or v4?

Comment: It is using v4.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markdown is designed to automatically parse URL's. If you don't want that to happen then you shouldn't use the Markdown format.

"plaintext" is not an available format type. You can use "plain" instead, but there is also a helper class called `TextFormatTypes` that contains all your choices so that you don't have to worry about typing the wrong thing.

```
var answer = context.Activity.CreateReply();
answer.TextFormat = TextFormatTypes.Plain;
answer.Text = $"{response}";
```